# Unable to Add Email Template to a Journey in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am unable to add Email Template to a Journey Builder.

In the Step 2 When I choose " Send Email" under activities I try to choose the Email Template but the towards the last step "DONE" is the Greyed.

Wondering if anyone had this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to acknowledge your confirmation by checking the box labelled `This information is correct and this email is ready to send.` It is at the top of that sub-window.